# How to make MPMoviePlayerController ignore the mute switch

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I want to play a video using `MPMoviePlayerController` but I want it to ignore the mute switch, similar to the behavior of Youtube's video player.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question should be protected by community.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `AVAudioSession` category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and your app will ignore the mute switch like the Youtube app.

For example (inspired by Ken Pletzer in the comments):

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

// note: you also need to add AVfoundation.framework to your project's 
// list of linked frameworks
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] 
                setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback 
                error:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Handle error here, as appropriate
}
```

Comment: More specifically
<code> 
    NSError* error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &error];
    if( error )
    {        
    }
</code>

Comment: Also need to add AVFoundation framework and #import "AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h"

Comment: @KenPletzer Thanks Ken, I appreciate your comment. I made a small tweak to your code (check success value rather than error's existence)  and put it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
_player.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Comment: This is deprecated as of iOS6

Comment: Any other alternative for property useApplicationAudioSession? I found that apple has no any replacement property for useApplicationAudioSession  :(

Answer (score 2):

in Swift: Do this once before you play sound/video (for example at the beginning of your application)

```
do{
  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
} catch {
  //Didn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future, I know this has been answered already, but I had an issue with playing a video in my app which caused apps like spotify, youtube etc. to stop playing it's audio, so I ending up using this:

```
NSError *silentSwitcherror = nil;
BOOL silentSwitchSuccess = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&silentSwitcherror];
if (silentSwitchSuccess)
{
//put whatever video code you are trying to play
}
else
{
//put how to handle failed instances.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you import AVFoundation just put this in your delegate:

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];